# hibernate @GeneratedValue correct?

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

I set my entity property

```
@GeneratedValue
Long id;
```

and I able to generate id for the entity in database. My question is why all the entities are sharing the same incremental number?  **aren't each table should start counting from zero?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the underlying database.
[GenerationType](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html) is AUTO by default, and Hibernate chooses one of the three variants depending on the database. If you want to use one in particular, set it as attribute of `@GeneratedValue`

Comment: i already set @GeneratedValue , so all entity now sharing same sequence.  i want each entity has it own sequence

Comment: i get error: could not get or update next value;nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammerException:could not get or update next value

Comment: problem sovled, i added the line <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

Answer (score 2):

This is database-dependent. JPA implementations use different ID generators depending on which database system they're using. For example, with Oracle, a single sequence will be created, and that sequence will be used to generate IDs for all entity types. By default, it will not create a sequence for each entity, since there's usually no reason to. The same logic applies to other database systems that use sequences rather than auto-increment columns.

I'm not 100% sure if the JPA API lets you change this behaviour, but I know that Hibernate annotations do. However, you haven't told us which database you're using or which JPA implementation you're using, so I can't give you much more advice than that.

Comment: i'm using oracle db and using spring-hibenateTemplate